# Sublime text3-python- build system [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I tried couple of different variants to solve my problem . 
I am trying to run python files trough sublime text .I dont know how to set up build system right way.

my python is install in : C:\Users\Nayeli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\

my sublime text3 in : C:\Program Files\sublime text 3

my scripts : C:\pythonscripts

I have tried cmd , without "shell true",with /D instead -u, with double \ instead / ...

```
{
    "shell_cmd": ["C:/Users/Nayeli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
    "shell":"true"
}
```

This is error i get:

[WinError 5] Access is denied
[shell_cmd: py -3 -OO -u "C:\Users\Nayeli\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\untitled.sublime-build"]
[dir: C:\Users\Nayeli\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User]
[path: C:\python37;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Nayeli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Nayeli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32]
[Finished]

Comment: The error output doesn't correspond with the build sample that you're providing. If you run `python` at a command prompt, does it work? If not, does `python3` work from a command prompt?

Comment: Yes it works at command prompt and from command prompt. Now i write code in sublime text 3 but i have to execute at Windows shell

Comment: It's hard to say why it doesn't work from Sublime if it works in the console, but as I mentioned previously the error output and the build system you provided don't match at all. If you can provide an example of a sequence of commands that works from the Console, it may be easier to construct a build file that works.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what you mean from a console. From my windows power shell ... I change directory to my folder pythonscripts, than i run > python file.py and thats how is executed. I watced few youtube videos that suggests the solution I posted above already.  I use now sublime text but i execute my files.py trough comand prompt. I cant execute them in sublimetext.

Comment: Sorry I tend to use console and terminal interchangeably, though in this case I shouldn't do that because Sublime has an internal console. If `python something.py` runs your program, then the built in Python build should work without having to do anything special or make a special build at all. You only need to create your own build if you're doing something more escoteric, like needing to activate a virtual environment or using something that's not `python` (e.g. `python3`).